# Javascript: Error keep showing even when all the conditions for the IF statement are no met

Tags: javascript

I have an IF statement in order to validate some things:

-If the input value is **different** from either **000000000000000000** (eighthteen zeroes) or **0** (one zero).

-if all the input has the same numbers

-if all the numbers in the input are only **0**

Code:

```
else if((IDProdAIngresar!='000000000000000000'||IDProdAIngresar!='0') && (allEqual(CantidadIngresadaSinPunto)) && CantidadIngresadaSinPunto.indexOf('0') > -1)
{
  $("#MSJ").html("Error: La cantidad ingresada no puede ser cero");
  $("#ModalMSJ").modal("show");
}
```

The problem is when the input is either **000000000000000000** (eighthteen zeroes) or **0** (one zero) the error keep showing when it shouldn't.

As I understand,if it's an **AND** all the validations has to be met for the error to show. However I have no idea why the error keep showing even when the `(IDProdAIngresar!='000000000000000000'||IDProdAIngresar!='0')` is not met and the other validations are, as shown in the image bellow:

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a logic error: `x != a || x != b` is always true, since `x` is always either not `a` or not `b`. You need `&&` instead.

Comment: "*f the input value is different from either 000000000000000000 (eighthteen zeroes) or 0 (one zero).*" an input of `"0"` (single zero) will return `true` here because it's not eighteen zeroes. And if you get `"000000000000000000"` that's not `"0"` so, `true` again

Comment: @ChrisG What should I do then? I cannot Use `&&` because then the error would never be shown?

Comment: @Roly _“because then the error would never be shown”_ — Why do you think that? What do you think does `a !== "1" && a !== "2"` return if `a = "3"`?

Comment: Can you please clarify which inputs are valid and which inputs are invalid?

Comment: Do you want `IDProdAIngresar` to *never* be either zero or eighteen zeroes? Then do `IDProdAIngresar == '000000000000000000' || IDProdAIngresar == '0'`. If you want `IDProdAIngresar` to *only* be one or the other and throw an error otherwise, then `IDProdAIngresar != '000000000000000000' && IDProdAIngresar != '0'` (or the equivalent but harder to read IMO `!(IDProdAIngresar == '000000000000000000' || IDProdAIngresar == '0')`).

Comment: @VLAZ thanks, I used the last you suggested and it worked.